# Flutter iOS override swipe back

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Navigator 2.0, I managed to override back button presses on Android with [`popRoute` override](https://medium.com/codex/flutter-case-study-catching-back-button-presses-on-android-when-using-navigator-2-0-d4d42e4718f6), but it doesn't works for iOS swipe back. Is there a way to override it ?

[image: swipe back screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots of what you're trying to do

Comment: With iOS, we can use a swipe from left to right, to handle back navigation (replacing traditional back button in Android). I added a screenshot of the behavior with AppStore. I want to override it so I can back on intermediate screen before the previous route. I have a routed widget for a particular feature with 2 steps in 2 screens. When I am on the second screen, I want to be able to return on the first screen of the feature, instead of the previous route.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this same problem. So, did you find a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @rashidotm nop, still looking. I want to remove Navigator 2.0 from my app to use the go_router. I hope that this issue (and others) will be easier to manage with it but can’t be sure before try.

Comment: Ultimately, I solve all the thing using the auto_route package